# 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After I update my `DC.edmx` model from the database I'm getting an error during the fetching of data from my "Users" table.

The exception is attached as a screen shot for a better understanding. I just wanted to know what this exception actually saying and what is the possible fix? Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.Username);
```

[Go here to see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9ipt.png)

Comment: Did you recently change ItemID?

Comment: No. I didnt changed that

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line that throws the exception and dig into ctx.Users?